# Creating Simple Quiz Logic in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

These are my Schema Tables

```
Schema::create('question', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->string('hint')->nullable();
            $table->text('explanation')->nullable();
            $table->string('referencematerial')->nullable();
            $table->string('imagepath')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('published')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

Schema::create('answers', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->boolean('iscorrect')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is my Classes for Question and Answer.

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'answer';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = array('text', 'iscorrect');

    public function Question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Question');
    }

}

class Question extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'question';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = array('title', 'hint', 'explanation', 'referencematerial', 'imagepath', 'published');


    public function Answer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Answer');
    }

}
```

My QuizController

```
public function index()
{
    $questions = Question::with('answers')->get();
    return $questions;
}

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2251:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::answers()
```

I have been trying to load the questions and answers on the page. It keeps giving me query builder error. Please feel free to chime into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is basically telling you that the relationship you have called (`answers`) doesn't exist.

You have called the relationship `Answer()` in your model but referenced it as `answers` in your query.

You either need to update the relationship in your model to `answers()` or change the query to `$questions = Question::with('Answer')->get();`

**Update**

Your relationship isn't calling the model correctly, it should be:

```
public function Answer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
```

Comment: I updated now it's this error. FatalThrowableError in Model.php line 869:
Fatal error: Class 'Answer' not found

I have called use App\Models\Answer; on top too.

Comment: @manshu Ah, this is due to your relationship not calling the model correctly. See my update, you just need to reference the `Answer` model correctly..

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.answer' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `answer` where `answer`.`question_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,

Comment: @manshu that is pretty self-explanatory - the table your `Answer` model references `myapp.answer` doesn't exist in your database yet. You have called the table `answer` in your migration but `myapp.answer` in your model.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'answer.question_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `answer` where `answer`.`question_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37,

Comment: @manshu again this is self-explanatory - just look at the error. The error is telling you that no column called `question_id` exists in your `answer` table. Looking at your migration for the `answer` table you haven't created this column. Just add it in and then run `php artisan migrate:refresh` to re-run your migrations and add in the new column.

Comment: i added everything. It works, but answers table is not returning anything. answer: [ ] <--- it's showing this in json.